# text area width and height doesn't change in table cell

Tags: php, html, css

I have this script and tried to change the width and height of the text area but there is no change when I run the code .

This is my code :

```php
<td style="width:200; height:400" width="200"> 
    <textarea name="teamnews_text" size="300" cols="32" class="form-control">
       <?php echo htmlentities($row_all_players['playerNews_text'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>
    </textarea>
</td>
```

Comment: Length in CSS always need a unit (unless the value is `0`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Textarea use `rows` (not size) and `cols` as attributes or `width` and `height` as style.

Answer (score 1):

textarea does not follow normal box sizing rules.

Try to add this css:

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code - Hopefully it will work for you

```
<td style="width:200; height:400" width="200" > 
<textarea name="teamnews_text" class="custom">
   <?php echo htmlentities($row_all_players['playerNews_text'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>
</textarea>
</td>


<style type="text/css">
.custom{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```